# how to send a notification if a terminal command takes more than x seconds?

Tags: unix, terminal, zsh

I'm looking for a way to send myself a notification for any process that takes over 60 seconds.

To send a notification I can use something like

```sh
notify-send -t 1 "hey command finished"
```

Is there a way I can save a `config` file somewhere or automate this behaviour in my `zsh`?

Similar to this [unanswered question from a different website](https://superuser.com/questions/471884/zsh-post-command-function-hook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your `.zshrc` file:

```sh
notify() {
  emulate -L zsh  # Reset shell options inside this function.

  # Fetch the last command with elapsed time from history:
  local -a stats=( "${=$(fc -Dl -1)}" )
  # = splits the string into an array of words.
  # The elapsed time is the second word in the array.

  # Convert the elapsed minutes (and potentially hours) to seconds:
  local -a time=( "${(s.:.)stats[2]}" )
  local -i seconds=0 mult=1
  while (( $#time[@] )); do
    (( seconds += mult * time[-1] ))
    (( mult *= 60 ))
    shift -p time
  done

  (( seconds >= 60 )) && 
      notify-send -t 1 \
          "hey command '$stats[3,-1]' finished in $seconds seconds"

  return 0  # Always return 'true' to avoid any hiccups.
}

# Call the function above before each prompt:
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook precmd notify
```